# Admin panel Ajax request value disappears

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, ajax, admin-panel

I'm trying to retrieve a value from the mysql db to be posted to a textbox on the admin panel.

I have everything working and connecting and returning the correct values.
When I step through the debugger, I see the values being assigned to the correct variables etc.

Problem I'm experiencing however, is that the values I retrieve, seem to disappear from the textbox after the function has finished processing.

phtml code:

```
function valChecker()
{

  var val = document.getElementById("test_attrib").value;

var url = '<? echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('machines/index/death'); ?>';

var response = "";

 new Ajax.Request(url, {
                    parameters:{test_attrib:val},
                onSuccess: function(transport){ 

        response = transport.responseText;
        document.getElementById("test_attrib").value = response;

                },
                  onFailure:  function(failer){
                  }
             });

}
```

if anyone would be so kind to assist please?

Comment: What is the value of `retval`?

Comment: @ Jayesh Patel, my bad, typo

Comment: Not an issue, see my answer and let me know if its fix the issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `textbox` value on AJAX `onSuccess` callback. Please find revised code as below:

```
var url = '<?echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')>getUrl('machines/index/death');?>'; 

var response = "";

new Ajax.Request(url, {
    parameters:{test_attrib:val},
    onSuccess: function(transport){ 
        response = transport.responseText;
        document.getElementById("test_attrib").value = response;
    },
    onFailure:  function(failer){
    }
});
```

It should worked.

Comment: okay, I made those changes, still the same. Values retrieved from the ajax call and assigned to response variable do not show up in test_attrib textbox

Comment: Please add whole function code in your question

Comment: alright, i edited my initial post with the code of the entire function

Comment: I guess the issue is `getElementbyId`, it should be `getElementById`. See updated answer.

Comment: *facepalm* ofcourse! Guess it was just one of "those days" again

Comment: Happy coding .... :)